# How to pass parameter to a store procedure in openrowset and sql-server authentication

Tags: sql-server, openrowset, sql-server-authentication

I have a store procedure with dynamic parameters `(@ parametr1, @parametr2)` and I wanna use it in an `openrowset` with SQL-SERVER authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do it with dynamic sql. Take care with the single apostrophes:

```
declare 
    @username sysname = N'MyUser', 
    @password nvarchar(32) = N'MyPassword', 
    @sqlinstance sysname = 'MYServer\MyInstance',
    @dbname sysname = 'MyDatabase',
    @query nvarchar(256);

set @query = concat
(
    N'select t.* from openrowset(''sqloledb'',''server=', @sqlinstance,
    ';Database=', @dbname,
    ';UID=', @username,
    ';Pwd=', @password,
    ';'', ''select somecolumn from someschema.sometable'') t'   
);
print @query;
exec(@query)
```

Comment: thank you. still I have the problem. how I can use it in Openrowset.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, my answer is using openrowset.

Comment: try it by `execute sp_executesql @query`